# Symbol for ground vs symbol for a battery

Tags: battery-charging, ground, charger, short-circuit, jumper

Could anyone help me to understand if this picture is correct?

It is to understand the difference between the symbol of a battery terminals and the symbol of a ground terminal.

[image: Symbols of ground terminal vs symbol of battery terminals]

I would also appreciate if anyone could help to me understand if this picture represents the situation if the positive terminal touches the chassis of one car in a jump-start.

[image]

Comment: you are trying to understand the difference between two incorrectly drawn symbols... your representation of the symbols is incomplete... both of the symbols include vertical lines ... the ground symbol includes one vertical line at top... the battery symbol includes a vertical line at top and one vertical line at bottom ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ground+symbol&iax=images&ia=images ... and... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=schematic+battery+symbol&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: your second drawing looks more like the symbol for an antenna than a ground.

Answer (score 1):

> It is to understand the difference between the symbol of a battery terminals and the symbol of a ground terminal.

1. The battery will have wires coming out of both sides. The ground symbol should only have a single wire coming out of the top.
2. The battery symbol always has an even number of lines, and they alternate long-short-long-short. If you're being fussy, there should be one pair of long and short for each cell in the battery. The ground symbol can have an odd number of lines and the lines become sequentially shorter.
3. The battery should be annotated with a device designator and possibly a voltage. The ground symbol needs no annotation unless there are several grounds (analog, digital, chassis, etc) in the circuit.

Annotations of "+" and "-" for the two terminals of the battery are not required as the longer line is understood to indicate the positive terminal.

> I would also appreciate if anyone could help to me understand if this picture represents the situation if a positive terminal touch the chasis of one car in a jump-star?

As I said above, if this is a ground symbol, there should be no wire contacting the bottom of the symbol. If it is a battery symbol it should have an even number of lines with alternating lengths (long and short).

As drawn, I'm not clear what the drawing is supposed to convey.

Comment: Well, _technically_ there should be one long-short pair for each cell in the battery.  I don't think there's very many people at all who actually do this in their schematics.

Comment: @TimWescott, read the 2nd sentence in my 2nd numbered paragraph.

Comment: I did.  I'm pointing out that the vast majority of people who draw schematics either disagree with that "should" or don't follow it.  I certainly don't follow it, and I think it would get confusing if I did.

Comment: @TimWescott, OK, edited.

Answer (score 0):

*This* picture represents a jump-start situation with the battery positive shorted to the chassis.  Note that the schematic capture program that's built into the site doesn't support the "three lines" ground symbol (or at least I couldn't find it).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUTbUf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much